# Подстановка слов в таблицу вместо числа для пользователя а программно остается число для расчетов?

Tags: javascript

Как можно сделать следующую операцию. Как видно в примере я вывожу числа в одну строку, а как заменить числа '1' и '2' внимание числа заменить на текст только для пользователя,а программно  числа остаются и с они подсчитываются в одну строку. До этого не сталкивался с такой проблемой, мануалы смотрел похожего не нашел.

```js
arr = [];
$('table tr td[data-name="mmessage1"]').each(function() {
var str = $(this).text() ? $(this).text() : 0;
$(this).text(str);
arr.push(str);
var ask=arr.join('');

$(".t").text(ask);

ask = String(ask);
while (ask.length % 3 > 0) {
    ask += '0';
}
result= ask.split( /(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/ ); 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
 
 <tr>
 <td>День недели</td>
 <td>Значение</td>
  </tr>

 <tr>
  <td>Понедельник</td>
  <td class="chenge " data-name="mmessage1"></td>
  </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Вторник</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">1</td>
  </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Среда</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">1</td>
  </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Четверг</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">1</td>
  </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Пятница</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">2</td>
  </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Суббота</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1"></td>
  </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Воскресенье</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Понедельник</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">1</td>
  </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Вторник</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">2</td>
  </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Среда</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">2</td>
  </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Четверг</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">2</td>
  </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Пятница</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1"></td>
  </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Суббота</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1"></td>
  </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Воскресенье</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1"></td>
  </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Понедельник</td>
  <td class="chenge " data-name="mmessage1"></td>
  </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Вторник</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">1</td>
  </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Среда</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">1</td>
  </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Четверг</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">1</td>
   </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Пятница</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1"></td>
   </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Суббота</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1"></td>
   </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Воскресенье</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1"></td>
   </tr>
 
 
</table><br>
<div class="t"></div><br>

<div class="tet"></div><br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var arr = [];
var text = ['Ноль', 'Один', 'Два'];//Тут мы объявим текстовые `алиасы`
var value, ask = '';//Незачем объявлять одни и те же переменные на каждый найденный итем, верно?
var numeric_value = '';
$('table tr td[data-name="mmessage1"]').each(function() {
  var num = $(this).text() ? $(this).text() : 0;
  /*Тут (+/-) начинаются основные изменения*/
  $(this).attr('value', num);
  $(this).text(text[num]);
  value = $(this).attr('value');
  numeric_value += text.indexOf($(this).text())*1;//Добавили эту cтрочку для числового вывода ответа
  ask += value;
  
  /*А тут они кончаются*/
})
//Прогонять цикл каждый раз для каждого элемента тоже не стоит, как и менять значение текста в нем
$(".t").text(ask);
while (ask.length % 3 > 0) {
  ask += '0';
}
result = ask.split(/(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/);

document.getElementsByClassName('t')[0].innerText += '\nСтрока из чисел - ' + numeric_value;

//Так можно проверить, что у каждой ячейки значение осталось неизменным
$('td').on('click',function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  Кликни на ячейку для отображения ее значения.
  <tr>
    <td>День недели</td>
    <td>Значение</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Понедельник</td>
    <td class="chenge " data-name="mmessage1"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Вторник</td>
    <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Среда</td>
    <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Четверг</td>
    <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Пятница</td>
    <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Суббота</td>
    <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Воскресенье</td>
    <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Понедельник</td>
    <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Вторник</td>
    <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Среда</td>
    <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Четверг</td>
    <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Пятница</td>
    <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Суббота</td>
    <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Воскресенье</td>
    <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Понедельник</td>
    <td class="chenge " data-name="mmessage1"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Вторник</td>
    <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Среда</td>
    <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Четверг</td>
    <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Пятница</td>
    <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Суббота</td>
    <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Воскресенье</td>
    <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1"></td>
  </tr>


</table>
<br>
<div class="t"></div>
<br>

<div class="tet"></div>
<br>
```

Comment: А если сделать наоборот, в таблице будут текстовые значения и из них подсчитать (0,1,2) вывести в одну строку, много ли нужно делать поправок ? https://jsfiddle.net/w0bw6fnf/2/

Comment: @Элиот, тогда нужно поменять строку `value = $(this).attr('value');` на `value = text.indexOf($(this).text());`. Обращаю внимание на регистрозависимость `indexOf`. В идеале, тогда и элементы массива `text` и сравниваемое значение нужно приводить к одному регистру, иначе могут проскочить нежелательные эффекты.

Comment: на выходе получилось 0-1-1-1-100-1-1-1-10000-1-1-1000, теперь от - избавится нужно и все отлично будет.

Comment: @Элиот, поправил ответ, числовые значения суммируются из ячеек в `numeric_value`, можно просто вывести одно за другим, если `numeric_value` - обозначить как строковую переменную.

Comment: обозначил $numeric_value как строковую переменную не выводит одно за другим. Я тут почитал может можно избавится от тире через регулярное выражение 0-1-1-1-100-1-1-1-10000-1-1-1000, пробовал в консоли `var s = '0-1-1-1-100-1-1-1-10000-1-1-1000';
s = s.replace('-', ''); ` удаляет не все пробелы

Comment: @Элиот, да никакие регулярные выражения тут не нужны. Смотри: 4я строчка кода - объявление переменной как строковой. 12я строчка кода(последняя добавленная, после нее коммент идет) - складывает все получаемые числа в строку. Как видно в примере, все складывается без `-`. Либо, мне ясны не все подробности.

Comment: может я не до конца точно выразился. Мне нужно удалить все тире тут 0-1-1-1-100-1-1-1-10000-1-1-1000 и мне нужно получить на выходе это число 011110011110000111000 а дальше я этот список чисел буду обрабатывать.

Comment: @Элиот, ну вообще лучше бы изначально подставлять числа без мусора. Да и это тянет на другой вопрос, либо поискать самому, но все же 
: `s.replace(/\D/g,'');` - решит проблему.

Comment: спасибо что помогли решить нюансы в моем вопросе:)

Comment: @ SLy_huh, последний момент, я ведь тут поставил наоборот в таблице текст ,а считал значения по цифрам, только сейчас обратил внимание что двоек нету у меня. строка 2 в JS. https://jsfiddle.net/w0bw6fnf/7/

Comment: @Элиот [Исправленная версия](https://jsfiddle.net/rLv0ecew/3/). Ты там напутал чутка, в коде. Убрал все лишнее, переставил поудобнее.

Comment: спасибо еще раз.